# Find distance to the origin of the tangent plane of $x^2-y^2+2z^2=5$ in the point $(2,-1,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I'm asked to find the distance to the origin of the tangent plane of the surface $x^2-y^2+2z^2=5$ in the point $(2,-1,1)$. This seems to be an optimization problem with constraint, which I think can be solved with Lagrange multiplier.

The tangent plane is of the form $f_x(p_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(p_0)(y-y_0)+f_z(p_0)(z-z_0)$ where $f_x=2x, f_y=-2y, f_z=4z$. So in that point, we get $4(x-2)+2(y+1)+4(z-1)$. This will be our constraint $g(x,y,z)$

The function we want to optimize is the Euclidian distance squared $(x-0)^2+(y-0)^2+(z-0)^2:=f(x,y,z)$

So with lagrange :$(2x,2y,2z)=\lambda(4,2,4)$ so $(x,y,z)=\lambda(2,1,2)$.

So $\lambda=\frac{x}{2}=y=\frac{z}{2}$ 
So $x=z=2y$

---

My questions are : 
1) Is what I did until now correct ? 
2) If yes, how am I supposed to find the given point(s) now ? I have everything expressed in term of one variable but how do I find the value of this variable ? I thought about plugging $x$ and $z$ in terms of $y$ into the original surface equation $x^2-y^2+2z^2=5$ but we're asked to find the distance of the tangent plane of that equation at a point, so the tangent plane of that point isn't necessarily member of that surface, or am I wrong ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You haven’t used your constraint, which is the equation of the tangent plane.

Comment: Note that the distance of a plane from the origin can be read directly from its point-normal equation, so casting this as a Lagrange multiplier problem is a bit overkill.

Comment: You’ve found that a critical point of the Lagrangian must have $x=z=2y$. Find a point on the tangent plane that satisfies this condition.

Comment: @amd Okay, but still. If we go it that way, what do you mean with " haven’t used your constraint" ? I used it as my constraint.

Comment: @amd Should I use $4(x-2)+2(y+1)+4(z-1)=0$ and solve for y ?

Comment: You seem to know that you have to plug into the “original equation.” In this case, that equation is the one for the tangent plane, not the surface to which you’re computing the tangent.

Comment: @amd Yeah, that's what I also said

Comment: @amd Quote: "I thought about plugging $x$ and $z$ in terms of $y$ into the original surface equation $x^2-y^2+2z^2=5$ but we're asked to find the distance of the tangent plane of that equation at a point, so the tangent plane of that point isn't necessarily member of that surface, or am I wrong ?"

Comment: So, what’s the problem? You’re trying to find a point on the tangent plane, not on the original surface.

Comment: @amd Yeah, so I just need to plug $x=z=2y$ in the equation of the tangent plane, is that correct ?

Comment: @amd I mean, use $4(2y-2)+2(y+1)+4(2y-1)=0$ and solve for y, do you agree with that ?

Comment: Sounds like the right approach to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

The tangent plane is perpendicular to $\nabla f$ where $f(x,y,z)=x^2-y^2+2z^2.$ (Why?) So its equation is given by $$2x-2y+4z=D.$$

Moreover, the plane contains the point $(2,-1,1).$ (Why?)

So, you have to get the distance from the origin to a plane.

Comment: Okay, so with your method, which is obviously much simpler than the one I chose, I just need to use the distance from point to plane formula, is that correct ?

Comment: Yes. When you have got the equation of the plane you only need the distance from the origin to the plane.

Comment: Just to be sure, the point $(2,-1,1)$ lies on the plane because it's stated so in the problem, otherwise they would not give us that point (And they would ask us to find the tangent plane in another point). And if I use your approach, to find D, I just plug that point into the plane equation $2x-2y+4z=D.$ and solve for D Then I use $\frac{0+0+0+D}{\sqrt{2^2+(-2)^2+4^2}}$, is that correct ?

Comment: Yes. You need the point $(2,-1,1)$ to get $D$ in $2x-2y+4z=D.$

Comment: @amd Well, I get two different results. With the point plane vesion, I get $D=10$ so distance=$\frac{10}{\sqrt{24}}$ but with Lagrange, I get $y=\frac{5}{9}$, so $\sqrt{(2y)^2+y^2+(2y)^2}=\sqrt{9y^2}=\frac{5}{3}$. Am I missing something ??

Comment: Using Lagrange note that $(2x,2y,2z)=\lambda(4,-2,4)$ instead of $(2x,2y,2z)=\lambda(4,2,4)$.

Comment: Yeah but that doesnt really change anything given that all terms are squared.

Comment: Using Lagrange it is $(2x,2y,2z)=\lambda(2,-2,4).$